# run c++ script multiple times which reads csv file

Tags: python, c++, r

I have a c++ console app to be ran multiple times. It reads a large csv  file everytime it runs which doesn't change . It is a slow process.
Is there any way to just "load" the file in memory and not have to read everytime I run the file.

I was thinking in ways R and python works. You load a csv as dataframe and can use it in other
R scripts without loading everytime.

Comment: What does your program do with the data? Would having a persistent "server" process help here?

Comment: it reads the data and stores it in arrays which are later used in other functions

Comment: That doesn't add any useful information to your explanation. If you need to work with this data repeatedly, maybe load it into a database and query it there. You need to be more specific about what you're doing with it.

Comment: Reading large csv's  as a 2d vectors and use them in other functions. I dont want to query databases just looking for some dirty hack/trick to reduce some runtime.

Comment: Using all of them? Some of them? One of them? It matters. Maybe memory-mapped files is the answer. Maybe not! How large is this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming most of time is wasted on CSV parsing, and not on file-system operations, you can store your parsed data to a new file using `fwrite`. On second execution, read the other file using `fread`, instead of parsing the CSV-file.

Pseudo-code:

```py
data = allocate()
open 'file.parsed'
if successful:
    fread('file.parsed', data)  # this is supposed to be fast
else:
    parse('file.csv', data)  # this is slow; will do only once
    fwrite('file.parsed', data)
```

Comment: This looks like  good hack. Can you provide some link/example for this, Say, i want to parse data in a csv as a 2d vector and store it.

Comment: You didn't provide code in your question, so I guess an answer without code should be OK for you. Just in case you need a link with examples, here: [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Answer (score 2):

Each time your C++ app exits, its memory will be freed, which implies that your data won't be kept for the next time. Therefore, if you store your data in your app memory heap, it should be read from file each time you run the app.

If you really want to avoid reading your data from the filesystem, the easiest path is to use a separated process, i.e. a in-memory database, such as Redis or SQLite, so you can read your cdv once, store it in the DB memory, and then access your data through your C++ app.

[List of In-memory DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases)

In your case, I would suggest to choose **Redis** (easier than SQLite since you don't need to create tables).

If you're not familiar with it, it's quite simple to start : Redis is a key-value storage system.
You just need to [install a redis server](https://flaviocopes.com/redis-installation/) for our environment, and you can use a C++ lib to immediately store and retrieve data in it. All you have to do is use two types of command: [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set) (when you read your CSV file for the first time) and [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get) (when you access the data for your processing purpose).

The simplest way to store your data is probably to store each line of your CSV with a key composed by the filename and the line number. For instance, if your file name is *artists_rock.csv*, you can do this to store the line 909:

```
SET ART_ROCK_909 "Lennon;John;Liverpool"
```

and you can get your record like that:

```
GET ART_ROCK_909
```

The key format is up to you, so that one makes it easy to iterate or access a line directly, just as if you were reading your file.

And if you use a C++ lib to parse your CSV records (meaning you never manipulate the original strings), you can also store your object as a *set* and manipulate it with [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset) and [HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget). The previous example would look like this:

```
HSET ART_ROCK_909 name "Lennon" fistname "John" birthplace "Liverpool"
```

and you would access data with

```
HGET ART_ROCK_909 birthplace
```

All you need to do is to choose a C++ lib to talk to you Redis server. There are many wrappers to the **hiredis** C library, such as redis-plus-plus that you can find on Github.

Here is a [getting started](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#getting-started) sample code.
To keep the same example as above, the corresponding code would look like this:

```
  #include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>
    
    using namespace sw::redis;
    
    try {
        // Create an Redis object, which is movable but NOT copyable.
        auto redis = Redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
    
        auto line = my_csv_reading_function();
    
        redis.set("ART_ROCK_909", line);
        auto val = redis.get("ART_ROCK_909");    // val is of type OptionalString. See 'API Reference' section for details.
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for some hack/trick which could do this without going too technical.Still,Can you provide some link/tutorial/code to implement this.

Comment: I just improved the previous answer to help you getting started with Redis.